# XML Edit in SSIS using Script task

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, xsd, script-task

Trying to include element in an xml which already contains data. The File needs to be processed part of a ssis package to bring in information on the server. Example of the xml file structure - I have included a subset of the xml where I am facing issue -

```
<ReportA>
    <Header>
        <Area>M</Area>
    </Header>
    <Year>2024</Year>
    <Type>A</Type>
    <Category>
    </Category>
</ReportA>
```

Using SSIS data flow task to read the XML it does not read the below, because it not nested with an element tag (minus the root element)
2024
A

Happy to share more information.

Expect all information to be read including Year and Type to make the data that already exists available to bring on the server

Update - Tried the below XSLT transformation to debug the structure and extract the Year information

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ReportA">
                <xsl:text>Found ReportA element.&#10;</xsl:text>
  
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="ReportA/Year">
                        <xsl:text>Found Year element as a direct child of ReportA.&#10;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ReportA/Year"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        
                        <xsl:text>No Year element found as a direct child of ReportA.&#10;</xsl:text>
                        <error>No Year element found as a direct child of ReportA</error>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>No ReportA element found.&#10;</xsl:text>
                <error>No ReportA element found</error>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XML you posted is valid.  I would use a online XML checker to validate the XML and make sure the entire XML file is valid.

Comment: There is some sensitive data , which limits me to include the XML in a checker as is, any way I can add dummy tags iterating through xml to make the data accessible? When I add manual dummy tags that information does read in the package. I did see this post and its reference to Russian Doll Design

Comment: SSIS XML Task has operation Transformation to apply XSLT to any XML file. Probably this route would be easier for your needs.

Comment: I usually check in VS. Go to menu  Project : Add new item : XML.  Then paste the XML into the XML window.  Errors will show like compiler errors in the Error List.

Comment: @jdweng - There shows no error in VS

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - I tried using XSLT operation in VS. Using the below code - it is unable to read the XML structure

Comment: There must be something wrong with the nesting.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-nested-for-xml-queries?view=sql-server-ver16#return-inner-for-xml-query-results-to-outer-queries-as-xml-type-instances

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.